# Secure way to communicate OAuth token to javascript client

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am designing a multi-platform application at the moment (clients would include internally developed mobile apps, and an AJAX heavy javascript client initially) centred around a REST API. Since in the future the API may be open to third parties, I am looking at using OAuth 2.0 for authentication and authorization with the API.

I am trying to get my head around some of the security issues with this arrangement, particularly with regard to the javascript client. I don't want this client to behave like a third party client might, with a whole bunch of redirects and popups and stuff, which is what most OAuth documentation seems to focus on. Since it will be delivered from my own domain, I am thinking that the server side of the webapp can be the actual client, and store the client secrets and refresh tokens, while the javascript retrieves new auth tokens from the server as it needs them.

To put it in step by step form:

1. The user logs in using non-ajax html form, generating auth and refresh tokens which are stored server side. This sets a HTTP-only login session cookie.
2. The javascript client code is sent to the user's browser after login.
3. The javascript client makes a request to a resource that is part of its own application (not part of REST api) to retrieve the token. The session cookie ensures that the client is genuine, and the referer will also be checked. Auth token is returned.
4. The javascript client validates the token with the REST API.
5. The client can now use the token to make requests against the REST API until it expires.
6. If the auth token expires or the page is closed and re-opened, the javascript client can  request a new token. The server side of the webapp takes care of refreshing the token and sends the new token, as long as the login session cookie is still valid.

Does this make sense, or would it leave massive holes in the system? In particular, is it insane to have a resource on the web that hands out authentication tokens based on a cookie being set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure that any communication to browser is HTTPS, so that no one in the middle can steal your tokens. And set the "secure" flag on your auth cookies.

- Most browser authorization schemes nowadays boil down to a session token that's passed in a cookie. The OAuth 2 scheme is a couple steps ahead because a) the tokens (can be) dumb tokens with no dangerous user info inside, and b) they expire.
- (Just to put that comment in context: one time I popped open a session token from a site and discovered my home address and phone number was in there. Ack!)
- I've seen code that does HMAC signing of requests inside the brower javascript, but it came with a huge disclaimer: don't use this in production. A signing scheme requires the client (javascript) to know a "secret" string, but the browser/javascript is so insecure that it amounts to handing your secret strings to the world.

But if you keep all your commuinication over HTTPS, then you're really just putting an OAuth twist on the familiar scheme of passing session tokens as cookies.

Comment: I was planning to use SSL for everything alright, I should have mentioned.

Comment: I agree with this answer and am considering implementing this approach as well, but there's another approach worth mentioning.

You could use an "implicit" grant from JavaScript, then use the access token to make a call back to your web app in order to generate a session cookie. From that point on, the session cookie (which is tied to the access token on the server-side) would be used to auth against the web app and the access token would be used to auth against the REST API. However, how do you handle the refresh token here (store it in local storage where available, perhaps?).